# Anybody know what plugin to create menu cycle like "http://water-park.gr" ?

Tags: jquery

may you can help me to make menu cycle like this website.
[water_park](http://water-park.gr)

or may be you can suggest me to use another plugin if any?
thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a custom script. You can review the souce code [here](http://www.water-park.gr/wp-content/themes/waterpark/js/hp-scripts.js?ver=1.0). As you can see, it's built with [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS).

Comment: Thank you jurgemaister i'll try to learn the code and TweenJS.